# Why does this LINQ not work? Im trying to get All Countries from a class (only countries

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get all Countries from my database for a combo box.
This is my code for it:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCountries()
        {
            var query = from e in Entities
                        select e.Country;

            return query;
        }
```

It gives me an error at `return query;`

I only want the Countries for my combo box, even though there are cities and all sorts in the Customer class.

Comment: When the compiler "gives an error", usually it gives details about the problem. Please include those in your question, in the future

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by using `IQueriable<string>` instead of `Customer`!

Comment: Your method may query "customers" but you Select just their countries, which apparently are stored as `string` (as is usual) - that's why `IQueryable<string>` is the correct return type

Comment: You may want to add a `Distinct()` and/or `OrderBy(s => s)` there, to get a more useful list